# Why do we have $\operatorname{Proj}(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i \left< x\right>^i)\cong \operatorname{Proj}(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i \left< x^2\right>^i)$?

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, graded-modules

I'm just curious but why is it that 
$$
\operatorname{Proj}\left(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i \left< x\right>^i\right)
$$
isomorphic to 
$$
\operatorname{Proj} \left(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i \left< x^2\right>^i\right), 
$$
where $\left< x\right>$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

$$
$$
*Note*: if the above is true, then isn't it reasonable to also have 
$$
\operatorname{Proj}\left(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i \left< x\right>^i\right) \cong \operatorname{Proj}\left(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i \left< x^k\right>^i\right)
$$ where $k\geq 1$?

$$ 
$$ 
*Edit*: In fact, is it true that $\operatorname{Proj}\left(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i I^i\right) \cong \operatorname{Proj}\left(\oplus_{i=0}^\infty t^i I^{ki}\right)$ for any $I \subseteq R$ and $k\geq 1$?

Comment: this is answered here, although only with a reference to an exercise http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46202/rees-algebra-for-non-radical-ideals

Comment: Thanks countinghaus! I will definitely take a look at that link.